# Alamofire url encoded request parameter not getting added

Tags: url, parameters, request, alamofire

I'm following Alamofire's CRUD and authorization section:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
```

So what I want to accomplish is basically a simple `PUT` request which looks like this:

http://localhost:8080/rest/users/add?id=

So in my code I have:

```
 let requestParam : [String : AnyObject] = ["id" : "\(SOMEID)"]
  Alamofire.request(Router.AddUser(parameters: requestParam))
    .validate()
    .responseString { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .Success:
     ..
```

However, following my server doesn't get this `id` parameter.

Debugging the `NSMutableURLRequest`, I find that the `id` parameter isn't added.

```
case .AddUser(let parameters):
        print(parameters)
        let encodedURL = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
        print (encodedURL)
```

Console output:

> ["id": 5649fec6d4c662c573d39fb4]
>    { URL: http://localhost:8080/rest/users/add }

This is really strange, because I had another method written almost identically but I wasn't getting the same issue.

**Edit:**

It turns out after some trials that it's because the method is `PUT`. If it was `GET` method then parameters were added correctly. Does anyone know why I can't put request parameters for `PUT`? Is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

In your router, why don't you use NSURLComponents to build your url and then return NSMutableURLRequest like that:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
  ...
  var URLRequest: NSMutableUrlRequest {
    var urlComponents = NSURLComponents()
    urlComponents.host = // something
    urlComponents.scheme = // probably wanna use https
    switch self {
      case .AddUser(let parameters):
      // set urlComponents.path here
      urlComponents.query = parameters.queryString
      // depending on your code you may want to check before force unwrapping URL below
      return NSMutableUrlRequest(URL: urlComponents.URL!)
    }
  }
}
```

then you can extend dictionary with a computed property of type String.

Hope that helps!